# Movie identification about defense shroud or aura

Tags: story-identification, movie

Several years ago I watched a movie that I only have vague memories of. One of the distinct memories of the movie is particularly frustrating because of the current irony. The most prominent scene I remember seemed to be set in a marketing meeting for a defense system or military contract. There was a male lead who the people in the meeting were congratulating (presumably for leading the marketing), but the lead was trying to figure out what the defense system actually was.

The lead said something very similar to "What is aurora?". The others in the meeting awed and oohed and said that's great when the lead responds again, "No, what IS aurora?". He genuinely didn't know or couldn't remember [hence the irony because I cannot remember what this is].

The second aspect I remember is much more vague. The lead was hallucinating a stereotypical farm truck coming at the character on the road and the character swerved to avoid the truck. The lead character's perspective flashed back and forth from the farm truck to several vehicles and people in suits coming to get the lead while he was crashed in the ditch in a concussion like state. Presumably, this was caused by "aurora", which the lead was trying to stop in some way.

I can state with 100% confidence the movie was pre-2010 and I can state with 90% confidence pre-2005, most likely several years before that. I have also considered "aurora" was meant to be "the aura" which makes sense if the defense system created a fake reality, but no luck in my searches. Unfortunately the tragedy in Colorado has made my search difficult looking for "aurora" references. I suspect the movie was an action movie/thriller, very confident not a scary movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[*Virtual Nightmare*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0244290/)" from 2000.

> [Dale](https://www.screenaustralia.gov.au/the-screen-guide/t/virtual-nightmare-2000/15230/) Hunter, a junior advertising executive on the fast track, begins to experience visions that the bucolic reality he lives in is a monumental scam. Seeking help from the local librarian, Wendy, a self-professed misfit, the two discover that the world they think they inhabit is actually a projection of a machine, the Direct Broadcast Virtual Reality. Designed to keep the populace happy and peaceful after a purported nuclear and chemical holocaust has decimated the Earth, the pair confront Andrew Blake, who controls the machine. When Dale and Wendy attempt to destroy the DBVR and restore the world to its natural state, they make an astounding and terrifying discovery."

The scene where the protagonist asks about the nebulous '***Aurora***' product his company has been tasked with advertising is linked below.

Comment: This answer is correct. I made a mistake somewhere on a login and somehow posted as a guest (strange), but this was my question and this was the answer. 39:40 is the other scene I remember. Looks like only one white van instead of several, but this is the movie. I am sorry I am unable to accept the answer because of the account mix up.